# Accessing "Google Accounts API" authenticated resources deployed on Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Another team in our company has an application deployed on Google App Engine and they are providing me with a way to access the data in the application through an API they've deployed. They are using Google Accounts API to do the authentication and we had a contractor last fall do a proof of concept that is partially working with a Python script which uses the gdata.service library and ClientLogin.

I want to redo this thing in Java, but am having a hard time finding information on how to authenticate to the application when I go to their URL. From what I've been able to find the ClientLogin method was deprecated and doesn't even exist in the Java libraries any more.

Can anyone point me to examples or documentation of how I can login to this application using the Google Accounts API from a Java client? All of the code samples and docs I've dug up so far are either seriously outdated or aimed at accessing Google API's.

The Python code that's working looks like this:

```
def auth(self, email, password):
    service = GDataService(service='ah')
    service.ClientLogin(email, password)
    authToken = service.GetClientLoginToken()
    authUrl = self.base_url + '/_ah/login?auth=' + authToken
    authResponse = self.opener.open(authUrl)
```

I just want to be able to do the same thing from Java.

Comment: Have a look at Oauth2 and federated login to understand the concepts : https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/GettingStarted From there you can find API's to implement you case.

Comment: In other words you are telling me that there is no longer a simple way to access web apps running on GAE that use Google Accounts API for authentication. The OAuth2 protocol is overkill for this. I have to register my "client app" (which is just a server to server backend app), get a private key of some sort, some other tokens, somehow get all that into GAE so that it knows who I am, perform some convoluted handshaking to an auth. What happened to a simple login using e-mail address and an application password?

Comment: Did you have a look at federated login as an alternative for Oauth2?. https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid

Comment: I don't have any control over the GAE side of things. They have it setup to use "Google Accounts API" for authentication, so that's what I have to work with. They have authorized my my gmail account to access the resource so somehow a gmail address has to figure into the authentication.